# How synchronization programs treat files/folders in use

Tags: sync, mirroring

I'm planning on setting up a synchronization software to mirror (one way) my main working drive on to a spare one as a simple backup solution, but the drive is 3tb so moving or working on files inside it during synchronization is hard to avoid, considering the time it will take.

My question is, are synchronization programs designed to handle file changes during sync? If I made a change after the software went through a particular folder, do I simply sync the differences afterwards to bring those changes up to date? Would doing this repeatedly over time eventually cause conflicts? How does this work?

I am currently trying out Synchredible and FreeFileSync

Thanks

Comment: Im note sure how this software works, but if you want to sync each change right after it happend then i would say you should consider bulding a raid 1 system.

Comment: I think those two softwares handle what you're looking for, the software can monitor file changes and handle it even if it's locked by another program. If there is a change that occurs in some part of the file, the software will just change that little part in the mirrored file (so do Dropbox for example). It's a fundamental technique to save resources. They also have conflict handling mentioned in the both official site and sourceforge.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, that is something I will set up eventually, but I currently don't have the time. This is posted more out of curiousity.

Comment: @TarekJellali - Thanks Tarek, I'm more curious as to whether this has to be done manually and how I can be certain that the result is an exact mirror?